# How open pdf file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, file, dart, pdf

How open pdf file in flutter?

I want to open a PDF file using programs (like ABOBO Acrobat, Polaris and So on) using flutter, How?
From asset or network.

Answer (score 1):

To open any file you can use the [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) package

```
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
OpenFile.open(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pub flutter packages like [Advanvace pdf viewer pub package](https://pub.dev/packages/advance_pdf_viewer)

[Or syscfusion flutter pdfviwer pub package](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ flutter_full_pdf_viewer 1.0.6 ] Dependencie
Here is the Code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_full_pdf_viewer/full_pdf_viewer_scaffold.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Plugin example app',
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String pathPDF = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createFileOfPdfUrl().then((f) {
      setState(() {
        pathPDF = f.path;
        print(pathPDF);
      });
    });
  }

  Future<File> createFileOfPdfUrl() async {
    final url = "http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
    final filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = await request.close();
    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return file;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Plugin example app')),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Open PDF"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PDFScreen(pathPDF)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PDFScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  String pathPDF = "";
  PDFScreen(this.pathPDF);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PDFViewerScaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Document"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.share),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
        path: pathPDF);
  }
}
```